# Highlighting in between html tags ( HTML, JavaScript, ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an API call in my program where the result is an HTML document. I have to show the HTML codes from the API result into my browser. I am also getting two integer values from the API (say, start_point and end_point). My requirement is to highlight the text in HTML document. The text is highlighted from the start_point value to the end_point value.
Assume the following HTML code is from my API

```
<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor init </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor init </p>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor init </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor init </p>
      </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor init </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor init </p>
  </section>
```

Now consider **start_point = 16** and **end_point = 32**.

So according to my requirement, since the start_point is 16 and end_point is 32, the counting starts from "<" of the <section> tag, and highlight starts from "r" of Lorem and end in "i" of init in the < h1> tag. So the above html will be shown in my browser somewhat like this:

Lo`rem ipsum dolor i`nit

Lorem ipsum dolor init

Lorem ipsum dolor init

Lorem ipsum dolor init

Lorem ipsum dolor init

Lorem ipsum dolor init

But now consider the case that the start_point is in the middle of some tag and end_point is after the closing of the same tag.

For example, consider **starting_point = 30** and **end_point = 50**. So my HTML highlight should look like this:

Lorem ipsum dolo`r init`

`Lor`em ipsum dolor init

Lorem ipsum dolor init

Lorem ipsum dolor init

Lorem ipsum dolor init

Lorem ipsum dolor init

#### Is there any way to achieve this?

Presently I am using a JavaScript code like this:

```
html.slice(0, start_point) + `<span id="highlightText">` + html.slice(start_point + 25, end_point) +`</span>` + html.slice(end_point);
```

Here <span id="highlightText"> takes 25 space, that is why I have added 25 to the second slice. This span with id "highlightText" is then given a background color. Since I have to close the span tag inside the container tag, it is not working. I dont want to use jQuery so please suggest pure JavaScript answers.

Comment: I don't think you should be counting html tags here since you are going to highlight the text on rendered DOM.

Comment: Then how can I achieve it? I have the value in the form of an HTML document. How will I count the text to add a background colour from start_point to the end_point ?

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found the solution. [MarkJS](https://markjs.io/) helped me to achieve what I actually needed. It handles the highlighting of text even if it crosses HTML tags. A perfect solution for my problem.